# Why does both the Interface and the Object use the same name in Android Studio Compose source code?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Android Studio Compose。

The Code A is from the artical [Layouts in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#4)

The `fun BodyContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)` make me confuse. I check the source Code B, I find the first `Modifier` in `fun BodyContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)` is an interface, and the second `Modifier`is an object.

I don't understand why Android Studio Compose source code use the same name for both interface and object, it make me confuse, I don't know whether the compiler of Android is confused too. :)

Why does both the interface and the object use the same name in Android Studio Compose source code ? Is it a good solution?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun BodyContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(modifier = modifier
        .background(color = Color.LightGray)
        .padding(16.dp)
        .size(200.dp)
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        content = {
            StaggeredGrid {
                for (topic in topics) {
                    Chip(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), text = topic)
                }
            }
        })
}
```

**Code B**

```
interface Modifier {
    fun <R> foldIn(initial: R, operation: (R, Element) -> R): R
    fun <R> foldOut(initial: R, operation: (Element, R) -> R): R
    ...

    interface Element : Modifier {
        override fun <R> foldIn(initial: R, operation: (R, Element) -> R): R =
            operation(initial, this)

        override fun <R> foldOut(initial: R, operation: (Element, R) -> R): R =
            operation(this, initial)

        override fun any(predicate: (Element) -> Boolean): Boolean = predicate(this)

        override fun all(predicate: (Element) -> Boolean): Boolean = predicate(this)
    }

    /**
     * The companion object `Modifier` is the empty, default, or starter [Modifier]
     * that contains no [elements][Element]. Use it to create a new [Modifier] using
     * modifier extension factory functions:
     *
     * @sample androidx.compose.ui.samples.ModifierUsageSample
     *
     * or as the default value for [Modifier] parameters:
     *
     * @sample androidx.compose.ui.samples.ModifierParameterSample
     */
    // The companion object implements `Modifier` so that it may be used  as the start of a
    // modifier extension factory expression.
    companion object : Modifier {
        override fun <R> foldIn(initial: R, operation: (R, Element) -> R): R = initial
        override fun <R> foldOut(initial: R, operation: (Element, R) -> R): R = initial
        override fun any(predicate: (Element) -> Boolean): Boolean = false
        override fun all(predicate: (Element) -> Boolean): Boolean = true
        override infix fun then(other: Modifier): Modifier = other
        override fun toString() = "Modifier"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not? The compiler is perfectly fine with it, and you'll get used to it once you've tried Compose for a few days, it's quite handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nothing wrong with the naming when you get used to it you start implementing your own classes same way.

Very basic structure for compose, i simplified and changed some parts for demonstration and be compatible with Kotlin only

```
fun Column(modifier: Modifier, content: ColumnScope.() -> Unit) {

    Layout(modifier) {
        ColumnScope.content()
    }
}

interface ColumnScope {
    fun Modifier.alignColumn()

    companion object : ColumnScope {

        override fun Modifier.alignColumn() {
            println(" Modifier for Column alignColumn() ")
        }

    }
}


interface Modifier {
    companion object : Modifier
}
 fun Layout(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,  content: () -> Unit) {
    println("Layout()")
    modifier.drawBehind {
        content()
    }
}

interface DrawScope {
    fun draw()
}

class DrawModifier(val onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) : DrawScope {

    override fun draw() {
        println("⚠️ DrawModifier drawContent()")
        onDraw()
    }
}

fun Modifier.drawBehind(
    onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit
) {
    DrawModifier(
        onDraw = onDraw
    ).draw()
}
```

And you can simply call this from a kotlin class and play on it to get familiar with compose.

```
fun main() {

    val modifier = Modifier
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        println(" Draw this COLUMN")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Code B` Modifier is not a class it is an interface and the interface is implemented within the interface itself using companion object and the comments also explain why they are doing that they want a empty modifier to start with. I think the reason they are doing this is to have same name for interface and the actual object maybe they didn't want to create separate object named `ModifierEmpty` just to keep things cleaner.

```
interface Test {
    fun test()
    
    companion object : Test {
        override fun test() {
            println("Test function called")
        }
    }
}

// Recognizes as type 
fun someFunc(test: Test) {}

// Calls from object and prints
Test.test()
```

You can also create this and this is perfectly valid code in kotlin when using this as type to `parameters` the compiler uses the `interface` and when directly calling the methods it uses the `object` inside the interface. This is confusing but just remember the object is within the interface and the compiler Figures out which one to use based on the context.